# Automatically runs Dolphin Browser on boot up

Tags: scripts, kiosk-mode

I am new here.

I have some android sticks. I use them to run a kiosk. That is some kind of newspaper on a big screen.

I runs in the dolphin browser.

I want that my clients just have to power on the screen and stick without having to click once.

Is this possible in adroid.

I use 4.2 and 4.3.

Comment: You might wish to check [other questions tagged `kiosk-mode`](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiosk-mode) – a tag I've just added to your question. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

you cant make dolphin run on startup, but you can use an app called Kiosk Browser Lockdown

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.procoit.kioskbrowser&hl=en

Comment: There are a variety of apps specifically dedicated to autorunning apps on startup, as well as apps such as Tasker that could accomplish similar. Your kiosk suggestion is a good alternative, but your assertion that you can't run Dolphin on startup isn't supported by the facts.